# What exceptions should I catch in an ActiveRecord Transaction block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't believe this has not already been discussed on SO but the helpful question completion widget didn't show one ...

The question is, akin to worrying about possible errors when attempting an HTTP connection, what "system level" exceptions should I catch when using `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`? I understand about catching invalid records and statements, caused by bad data; but what about all the ways in which the database connection and/or transaction might fail for reasons outside my app's logic's control?

Comment: The only one I'm aware of is the rescue Timeout::Error.  You also need to maker sure you use save! and update! as the regular versions will not make an exception and trigger a rollback.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the transaction is that if an error is raised at any point in the transaction block everything is reverted.  So you don't need to check for any of that.

You certainly want to see if *everything* succeeded or failed but individual statements in the block you don't need to check.

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear - the transaction block propagates all exceptions except Rollback, so the app has to handle these cases and message the client/user appropriately. O/w, the app as a whole will generate an HTTP 500 and an InternalServerError-type exception which I don't want. I can indeed rescue `StatementInvalid` and then check what went wrong; but even if all the data is correct, the adapter/connection/server might all throw errors that the app can't predict. Right? LMK if this makes sense - I'll edit the question.

Comment: @sameers I'm just as confused — where do the transactions come into play? Exception handling is the same, whether you use them or not. As for `StatementInvalid` exceptions: the docs [warn not to rescue them inside a transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Exception+handling+and+rolling+back).

Comment: Oh, gah, I am screwing this up with each comment :) I meant, `RecordInvalid`, not `StatementInvalid` :( And yes, I guess my question is the same, whether I use transactions or not, now that you say it. To wit, what litany of errors can ActiveRecord throw when something happens between it and the database server? @fatfrog mentions one - `Timeout::Error` in a comment.

Comment: @philip but we need to know what exceptions it might raise, so that we can catch them finally probably in controller or somewhere, so users don't see 500.